# Turbolinks is compatible with rails v7+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are working on rails upgrade from v6.1 to v7.0, we are using turbolinks and as we know rails 7 now has turbo inside hotwire. I'm not seeing any depreciation for turbolinks gem, but still curious  if we are able to use turbolinks in rails v7+ or not without migrating to tubo-rails gem.

I want know if turbolinks still compatible for rails v7+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks is still compatible with at least Rails v7.0.4.2 (and probably more, but this was the last version I used it with).

That said, Turbolinks is no longer being actively developed as stated on their [Github repo](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks). The migration from Turbolinks to Turbo is also quite simple and almost a drop in replacement though (see [here](https://dev.to/coorasse/from-turbolinks-to-turbo-31jl)), so I would highly recommend completing it anyways to avoid issues further down the line.